# Saving photo Ionic-Angular-Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

I'm trying save a simple photo using tripod Ionic-Angular-Capacitor and getting this error:

> Error: Cannot create Root directory
> at FilesystemWeb.mkdir (web.js:233)
> at async FilesystemWeb.mkdir (web.js:240)
> at async FilesystemWeb.mkdir (web.js:240)
> at async FilesystemWeb.writeFile (web.js:139)

```
//saving method
private async savePicture(cameraPhoto) {
  const base64Data = await this.readAsBase64(cameraPhoto);
  const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
  try {
    const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: '/fullpath',
      data: base64Data,
      recursive: true,
    });
    return {
      format: 'png',
      filepath: fileName,
      webviewPath: cameraPhoto.webPath
    };
  }
}
```

The photo's base64 is been generated, and I've tried the Base64, URi and DataUrl result type

```
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  quality: 100,
  saveToGallery: true
});
const savedImageFile = await this.savePicture(capturedPhoto);
```

Comment: Are you getting this in the browser or in android/iOS?